# WPF Image.Source and Transparent Graphics

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage

I'm creating a visual which can have some Images as well. If I use the normal (non-transparent) Png images its working fine (in terms of performance and printing) however as soon as I replace a single transparent png, it becomes very slow and takes more than 3 times of time in printing the visual as well.
I'm using the following code.

```
  var source = new Uri(filePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

  BitmapImage imageBitMap =new BitmapImage(source);

        var pictureImage = new Image();

        pictureImage.Source = imageBitMap;
        grid.Children.Add(pictureImage);
```

I used the ANTS Performance profiler and here are the statistics,

Using 4 graphics (Non-Tranparent) each approximately (50 -100KB) the average time to render them was 10ms for each graphic.
Soon I replace one of them with equivalent Transparent graphic, the average time shoots up and goes up to 34 ms for each graphic.

Any ideas why it takes that long for transparent graphics and how can I reduce it.

I tried to convert the tranparent Pngs into xaml using Adobe Illustrator and InkSpace as well but without success.
The Adobe Illustrator Plug-in, converts the png to 1KB xaml file with having an empty canvas with viewbox in it.
The InkSpace is converting the whole image into base64 string and setting it as source of the Image tag but that is not displaying in the visual at all.